# Text from one textbox to another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox

I have a textbox as

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SingleUnitBarcode, new { @class = "form-control",@id="barcode1", onblur = "CloneData" })
```

And on losing focus from this textbox I want the text in it to be displayed in another textbox(with id =customerbarcode_field)

I am using the javascript

```
<script>
    function CloneData() { 
        var value = document.getElementById("#barcode1").value

        document.getElementById("#customerbarcode_field").value = value;
    }
</script>
```

However the function is not being triggered when I lose focus from the first textbox.

What did i miss ?

Comment: why you not use jquery??

Comment: `onblur = "CloneData()"` <-- notice the brackets, also remove the starting `#` inside `getElementById`

Comment: @KyleNeedham , thx, the # was also the root of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the TextBox like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SingleUnitBarcode, 
                new { @class = "form-control",
                      @id="barcode1", 
                      onblur = "CloneData()" })
```

and script like this, in **javascript** you are mixing javascript with jquery:

```
<script>
    function CloneData() { 
        var value = document.getElementById("barcode1").value

        document.getElementById("customerbarcode_field").value = value;
    }
</script>
```

if you want to do with **jquery** then:

```
<script>
        function CloneData() { 
            var value = $("#barcode1").val();

            $("#customerbarcode_field").val(value);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the `onblur=CloneData`, to the the following one:

```
onblur=CloneData()
```

Also, you have to change the selecting of the DOM elements. I mean you should change the`#` tag in the `document.getElementById()` method. There we pass the `Id` of the DOM element we want to select without prepending the `#` before the `Id`. For instance, you should use this

```
document.getElementById("customerbarcode_field")
```

insted of this

```
document.getElementById("#customerbarcode_field")
```

If you were using `JQuery`, then you would have selected this element as:

```
$('#customerbarcode_field')
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `onblur = "CloneData"` by `onblur = "CloneData()"` and remove `#` from id

```
function CloneData() { 
    var value = document.getElementById("barcode1").value

    document.getElementById("customerbarcode_field").value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SingleUnitBarcode, new { @class = "form-control",@id="barcode1", onblur = "CloneData" })
```

with this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SingleUnitBarcode, new { @class = "form-control",@id="barcode1", onblur = "CloneData();" })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to put your javascript event in the html in that manner.  Since you are using jquery already you can attach a listener without polluting your html;

```
$("body").on('blur', '#barcode1', function(){
     $("#customerbarcode_field").val($(this.val());
});
```